# Why use ng-template instead of just *ngIf

Tags: angular

Any reason to use:

```
<div *ngIf="show; else notShow">content</div>
<ng-template #notShow>other content...</ng-template>
```

Instead of:

```
<div *ngIf="show">content</div>
<div *ngIf="!show">other content...</div>
```

Comment: You may prefer the first version if the `ngIf` condition is more complicated.

Comment: I would imagine the same reason one might use an “else” statement in general. If they weren’t useful, they wouldn’t exist.

Comment: Some people prefer to place their `<ng-template>` at the bottom or top of the template file. This can make the HTML a little easier to read, because then/else content does not add noise to the template where the business logic is being shown. `<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>` is just smaller, and the templates can be elsewhere in the HTML file.

Answer (score 8):

Angular wraps the host element (to which the directive is applied) inside `<ng-template>` and consumes the `<ng-template>` in the finished DOM by replacing it with diagnostic comments.

1.`<div *ngIf="show">content</div>`

Above will be converted to below code snippet in the DOM.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="show">
  <div>content</div>
</ng-template>
```

Angular replaces the `<ng-template>` with diagnostic comments.

So if you inspect it will be like:

```
<!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-if":"true"
}-->
<div>content</div>
```

---

2.`<ng-template *ngIf="show">content</ng-template>`

This will be treated as:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="show">
  <ng-template>content</ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

In DOM it will be

```
<!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-if":"true"
}-->
<!---->
```

---

For the first snippet of your code

```
<div *ngIf="show; else notShow">content</div>
<ng-template #notShow>other content...</ng-template>
```

This is how its rendered in DOM

[image]

For second snippet

```
<div *ngIf="show">content</div>
<div *ngIf="!show">other content...</div>
```

This is how its rendered in DOM

[image]

---

Please go through this article, it has a clear explanation for your question. [ng-template](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691)

Comment: Nice answer. I did not know that structural directives were rewritten into `<ng-template>`.

Comment: Apparently yeah, i too figured out recently :)

Answer (score 6):

It is purely semantics. There is no performance advantage between the two examples. So it doesn't matter which one you use. The key difference here is that the *else* syntax is procedural. You can reference a component property named `notShow` which is a template you created at run-time. You are just using the shorthand reference `#notShow` to use the `<ng-template>` in the current template.

Here's the source code for `*ngIf`:

```
private _updateView() {
  if (this._context.$implicit) {
    if (!this._thenViewRef) {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
      this._elseViewRef = null;
      if (this._thenTemplateRef) {
        this._thenViewRef =
            this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (!this._elseViewRef) {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
      this._thenViewRef = null;
      if (this._elseTemplateRef) {
        this._elseViewRef =
            this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._elseTemplateRef, this._context);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `this._context.$implicit` is the conditional expression from the template.

In either case, the `this._viewContainer.clear()` is called no matter what. So I don't see a performance difference in your examples.